# Transformation matrix for a 3d->2d projection

Tags: matrices, transformation, matrix-equations

We know $\mathbf{\hat{y}} = X\mathbf{w}$ and $A$ is the subspace in which $\mathbf{\hat{y}}$ lies (so the columns of the $X$ matrix define the subspace $A$).

$\mathbf{\hat{y}}$ (2-dimensional vector) is a projection of $\mathbf{y}$ (3-dimensional vector) onto $A$ (see image). The transformation of $\mathbf{y}$ to $\mathbf{\hat{y}}$ is $\mathbf{\hat{y}} = B\mathbf{y}$. So what is the matrix $B$, in terms of $X$?

[image]

Comment: What is $\mathbf{w}$?

Comment: A random 2d vector. Does it matter?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

Basically, since $\mathbf{\hat{y}}$ is a projection of $\mathbf{y}$, then $\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{\hat{y}}$, which is $\mathbf{y}-X\mathbf{w}$, is orthogonal to the subspace defined by the columns of $X$.
So:
$$X^T(\mathbf{y}-X\mathbf{w})=0$$
$$X^TX\mathbf{w}=X^T\mathbf{y}$$
$$\mathbf{w}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\mathbf{y}$$
And:
$$\mathbf{\hat{y}}=X\mathbf{w}=X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\mathbf{y}$$
Therefore $B=X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$.

Comment: Good job. You might already know, but this is called the [orthogonality principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality_principle) in estimation theory.